# HTML code in input value does not show up

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

When I use this code:

```
<textarea value="<?php echo $content['content']; ?>"></textarea>
```

$content['content']:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr><th>Age</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>Zach</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>Tyler</td></tr>
</table>
Yep.
```

to get post content from my database, this is all that shows up in the `<textarea>`

```
<tr><th>Age</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>Zach</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>Tyler</td></tr>
</table>
Yep.">
```

I tried using `htmlspecialchars()` around `$content['content']`, but that didn't work. Any ideas?
NOTE: $content is just a associative array fetched from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Textarea`s don't use the `value` attribute. Put it between the tags like so:

```
<textarea name="myhtmltextarea" rows="5" cols="40">
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($content['content']); ?>
</textarea>
```

See here for more info on supported attributes and uses: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea><?php echo $content['content']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: You still have to escape it.

Comment: While this answers the question, you didn't explain why. Note the other answer did explain and was selected as the correct answer. SO is not just about answering questions, but educating users.